# Hold and Release the data

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am developing a `Spring` Application in which many `users` would access that application at a time, now the scenario is if one user `hold` the `particular data` from `database` the other user shouldn't access that particular data until it get release, like as **Review** in `stack overflow`, give some suggestion to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DB objects cache in your app. When user 1 requests an object (eg by ID) you read it from db, place it in the cache, lock it and remember who locked it (there should be a lock and lockedByUser fields in the object) and return it to user 1. When user 2 requests the same object you block him until lock is released or throw an Exception. It's just a basic idea.